# Connect to Prometheus from PromLens in Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose, prometheus, promlens

I want to run the [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) and connect [PromLens](https://promlens.com/) to it.

I've written the following Docker Compose file:

```yaml
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.50.1
    ports:
      - 9090:9090

  promlens:
    image: prom/promlens:v0.3.0
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

I can open both:

- http://localhost:9090/ for Prometheus
- http://localhost:8080/ for PromLens

But when I open [PromLens](http://localhost:8080/) I can't connect to Prometheus via http://prometheus:9090/

```
Error validating server health: Failed to fetch
```

[image: connection failed]

How I can connect to Prometheus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I have to specified address not inside Docker environment but in my real. So connection http://localhost:9090 is working.

[image]

I suppose that PromLens working as browser app and connects from browser and not from inside the container.